# Sluggishness Observed while navigating between multiple screens in Worklight Application

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

These `jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js` and `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` are auto included in all of my HTML pages, while developing the UI screens using jquery mobile.
But this Auto-added JS files causes a `delay/sluggishness` while navigating between the multiple screens.

Is there any way to improve the sluggish behaviour?

Comment: jQuery Mobile is not "auto-added" to your applications - you created an application and selected to add jQuery Mobile to it. 1) You are not forced to use it. Use whatever you want. 2) Provide more clear examples of that "sluggishness", like a demo project, and mention your Worklight version, the environment you are testing in, and basically - help us help you, because right now, you're not...

Comment: I am using Worklight 6.1. I included jquery-mobile library 1.4.2 to draw the UI screens in my application. So when I use the jquery-mobile widgets or any other jquery-mobile elements the below scripts and some css files get included in all my pages which are causing the delay in my navigation : 
<script src="jqueryMobile/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
I navigate between pages as follows :    $("#pagePort").load(path + "pages/MainMenu.html");
If there any way to solve this problem? Please help me with it.

Comment: You still did not demonstrate the sluggishness. I have used jQuery Mobile many times and did not observe this behavior. You are claiming for sluggishness, then produce a demo Worklight project showing this sluggishness.

Comment: There is no way Idan i could provide you with code snippet here. So i am mailing you with ref as this question link.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Worklight 6.1 project you've emailed me, added the Android environment to it and ran it in the Android Emulator(!) (with API level 19 - Android 4.4) and did not observe any sluggishness.

In fact, your application does not even contain any animations. The pages simply switch from one to another. So, no slowness even in the emulator...

You'll need to create a test case application demonstrating what you are referring to because right now it is not reproducible. Also mention if you are testing it on a device or not - which device model and which Android version.

Comment: We are testing it on the devices. In the following devices we tested this demo project and it is user observable delay:Sony experia C(Android O.S 4.2.2), Samsung galaxy S3(Android O.S 4.3), Samsung galady Grand Duos(Android O.S 4.2.2 ).

Comment: I don't have these devices (or any Android device until Sunday). Can you upload a video file to dropbox that shows it?